# How can I sendEmail to two addresses at once?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET, so I hope I'm providing the right context and information here.

I have a (pre-existing) form that looks like this:

```
protected void sendEmail(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.recaptcha.Validate();
        if (this.recaptcha.IsValid == true)
        {
            lblResult.Visible = false;
            String from = "donotreply@website.com";
            String to = "test2@website.com";
            String to2 = "test1@website.com";
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to2));
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost");
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

Based on what I've googled, using `mail.To.Add` twice is the proper way to send the resulting mail to two separate addresses -- but unfortunately, I've had no luck at all. Nor does separating two addresses using a comma or semicolon work.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: That looks correct, are they both known good email addresses?

Comment: Which MailMessage is it? System.Net.Message or System.Web.Mail;

Comment: @CheGueVerra `System.Net.Mail`, actually.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yes, they're both known good addresses.